# Testing for multiple determinants in cox

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, multivariate-testing, determinants

I'm doing an analysis where I want to find what are determinants for (cardiovascular) events in my cohort of patients. I want to do a cox analysis (`coxph` from the `survival` package). Now I want to find which determinants are *independent* determinants.

Now the question is: do I simply make one model in which I throw all my prespecified determinants (age, gender, BMI, cholesterol levels etc) and then see what happens? Or do I have to do univariate testing first? And then only add the significant/near significant (e.g. p value <0.10) in the full cox model?

This was the model I am using now:

```
 model1 <- coxph(Surv(time,event==1)~age+gender+ckdepi+smoking+cholesterol+hdl+bpsys+t2dm+bmi, data=data)
```

And this is my output:

```
          coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z       p
age       0.04235   1.04326  0.00911  4.65 3.3e-06***
gender   -0.36583   0.69362  0.11538 -3.17 0.00152**
ckdepi   -0.01078   0.98927  0.00309 -3.49 0.00048***
smoking   0.14560   1.15674  0.03070  4.74 2.1e-06***
chol      0.10312   1.10862  0.03746  2.75 0.00590**
hdl      -0.04485   0.95614  0.13231 -0.34 0.73465
sysbp     0.00356   1.00357  0.00225  1.58 0.11392
t2dm      0.39539   1.48496  0.11763  3.36 0.00078***
bmi      -0.00898   0.99106  0.01227 -0.73 0.46427

Likelihood ratio test=97.4  on 9 df, p=0
n= 3084, number of events= 525 
   (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Also, I THINK I need to do testing for linearity (e.g. use restricted cubic splines or addquadratic functions) in the fully adjusted model, but I'm not sure. Is this correct?
In that case, my next step would be to test at least ckdepi and bmi since I'm pretty sure they might not be linear.

Comment: There can be many reasons for the insignificant p values. One of them is non linearity. It might also be because the coefficients are time dependent or the parameters themselves are time dependent. Also, the check for non linearity comes later when you check for model diagnostics - such as the proportionality assumption. I believe the univariate testing has nothing to do with the cox model. I think you are on the right track. Although you could check for interactions between variables (ANOVA) and see if the interactions improve your model. Hope this helps.

Comment: You should try `Cross Validated` for statistics questions. https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ...but `coxph` does not require univariate testing beforehand. The coefficients indicate roughly how important they are. If you think certain features have a non-linear relationship, you can also transform your features manually using a model (for example, exponential) you think is appropriate. For instance, you could use `age^2` instead of `age`.

Comment: @P.Routh: Thanks for you response. When you say check for interactions between variables (ANOVA), do you mean that running `anova(model1)` should show me what interactions there are? I wouldn't know how to see that. Or do you simply mean running e.g. 'coxph(Surv(time,event==1)~age*gender+ckdepi+...etc)' to see what interactions there are? And thanks for the response on checking for non linearity, I'll do that in a later step.

Comment: @ChiPak: In retrospect, you might be correct that Cross Validated would be a better choice for this question.

Comment: @TamarV. if two independent variables have interactions then you need to first build a model - `lm(y ~ x1*x2)` and see if the interaction is significant by investigating the anova table by running `anova(model)`. But I wouldn't carry out an interaction procedure unless I have sufficient reason to believe there might be one. Including interaction complicates the interpretation of the model - which is one of the caveats of the coxph model

Comment: @P.Routh: Yes, I've done that before in the past when I was interested in just one determinant, so I know that everything I do needs to have sufficient reason;) I just got confused because I'm not interested in multiple determinants at once and I was unsure how to do that. So say I suspect that gender is an effect modifier for the relation between smoking and events, I would do `anova(lm(event_n~smoking*gender))` and if smoking:gender has a p value <0.05, there is a significant interaction? Is that the right interpretation of your comment?

Comment: @TamarV. Yes I would do that. If the interactions are indeed significant, you should try building multiple `coxph` models with and without interactions and compare your findings to find a suitable model. You might find this answer helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179105/interaction-effects-in-cox-model-continuous-dichotomous-and-categorical-varia